# Different predictions for the same test set data having different levels in the factor variables in R (Ranger)

Tags: r, categorical-data, predict, train-test-split, r-ranger

I have a training data `train`having `distance` and `dest_zip_code` as predictor variables to predict `delivery_days`. I am using `ranger` RF model to create the 'Quantile RF regression' model object. Please note that the `dest_zip_code` levels in the training_data are based on 6 months.

Now, I have two identical test sets `test_A` and `test_B`

- `test_A` has `dest_zip_code` from last 2 months and levels are also based on last 2 months.
- `test_B` has `dest_zip_code` from last 2 months but levels are refactored to last 6 months (same levels as train data)

When I use the `predict` function on both the test sets with the same trained model object, at-least half of the predictions are different.

1. Can someone help me understand how the different factoring levels of test data with same observations is affecting the predictions?
2. Which one is theoretically correct?

Comment: wre you able to get an answer to this?